K(Ubuntu) 24 sound problem
I have a sound problem. I found the same topic on Reddit, but there is no answer, so I just copied and pasted the question from there:

"I have Kubuntu 23.10 installed and since a few days I have no sound:
'no output or input device found". I found a few solutions on internet
but they speak about alsa and pulseaudio but Kubuntu uses pipewire by
default I believe. I have sometimes this issue but after restarting
the laptop or upgrading the packages from Discover, the issue is
resolved but this time it doesn't. Any idea how to resolve this issue
? Thanks


Please be precise with details; Kubuntu doesn't have a 24 release (or snap only like Ubuntu Core 24) so do you mean Kubuntu 24.04 LTS?   Also what trouble shooting have you done?  eg. did you follow https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-broken.html.en  as the base of your system is a Ubuntu one thus this will match, but your using KDE Plasma (not GNOME) will mean how you follow steps varies due to your chosen desktop/GUI.

Yes i mean 24.04 LTS
Trouble shooting described in topic starter above: no output or input device found
Accordingly no sound is coming from the laptop.
I tried:

sudo apt update

sudo apt install pipewire

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/wireplumber-upstream

sudo apt update

sudo apt install wireplumber```
